# Play video fullscreen from Watson chatbot

Tags: chatbot, watson-conversation

I'm creating a chatbot using watson and integrate it into Facebook Messenger or skype. At some point I would like to show a video to the user. I have read that this can be done by using HTML (embedding the video in Facebook Messenger).

Is there also a possibility to show the video in fullscreen (embedding in Facebook Messenger would not be fullscreen)? So the goal is to play the video in fullscreen and after having the video played automatically returning to Facebook Messenger for continuing the chat with the bot.

Edit: I have to specify it more. I thought about providing the user a link to a video file stored locally on the smartphone (or just a preview image of the video the user can click on it). When the user clicks on it a video player opens and plays the video. After the video is finished it returns to the Messenger chatbot.

Comment: I sure hope not. If an app can go to full screen mode without the user intentionally choosing it, that means it could display a fake desktop without the user's knowledge.

Comment: @CareyGregory I have made an edit for clarification